# PHP if variable definitely is either value or value then

Tags: php, string, variables, if-statement

I want to do a quick check to see if a user has access to view the page and so I have the function which simply returns the users access level when called and made that into a variable but would like to know how to write the `if` statement...

This is what I have so far:

```
if($uac_check == "Owner" OR "Admin") {

    echo "You have Access";

} else {

    echo "No access for you!";

}
```

Is anyone able to help please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to test the value of `$uac_check` again.

```
if($uac_check == "Owner" or $uac_check == "Admin") {
```

Boolean operators like `or` and `and` need a boolean value on both sides of them.  When you have an expression like $uac_check == "Owner", it evaluates to a true or false value, also known as a "boolean" value.  You have `$uac_check` on the other side.  Most variables will evaluate to true when cast as a boolean value unless they are empty, null or 0.  That's likely to give you results you don't expect.

Note that I re-wrote the `OR` operator as `or`.  Both are valid, and so is `||` .

One last note - you can make tests more specific to avoid "misunderstandings" in PHP.  PHP is very lax about types, so it will tell you that `"1" == 1` and `0 == false` are true, when the 1 character and the number 1 are not the same thing, nor are 0 and false equal.  You can avoid mistakes like this by using the `===` operator, which checks both value *and* type.  This can be very important, especially with certain functions that can return 0 and false with two very different meanings.  It's called the `identical` operator.  You can read more about comparisons in the PHP manual on the [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) page.

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks! What is the difference to doing `OR` and `||`?

Comment: @AaronHatton - I added that to my answer.  Short version - there's no difference.

Comment: I'm glad I can help.  I threw in one last note that I thought might help in the future about how to prevent PHP from being so lazy when comparing values.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want [ternary operator](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/3/12/4).

```
$access = ($uac_check == "Owner" || $uac_check == "Admin") ? 'You have Access' : 'No access for you!';
echo $access;
```

Comment: This would be perfect however I intend for the content to be HTML rather then just one line, thank you anyway!

Comment: You can offcourse create php variable with html string and add it to access.

Comment: I know that however I am trying to keep my code as clean as possible and readable should I need to edit it later or if I get hit by a bus and someone takes over. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
if($uac_check == "Owner" || $uac_check =="Admin") {

    echo "You have Access";

} else {

    echo "No access for you!";

}
```